# Outlook running super slowly after syncing with exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am seeing a weird issue in Outlook 2016.

I have `User1`, `User2`, `Computer1`, `Computer2`.

`User1` on `Computer1`

- Outlook works as normal, but ocasionally seeing unread message notification in folder panel with no new messages in inbox.
- To fix the above, user is scrolling to the bottom of the inbox and clicking **Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange**
- After clicking that link, the messages all load, but from then on Outlook is super slow - clicking on an email takes ~1-2 minutes to view. It is unusable.

`User1` on `Computer2`

- This works perfectly - there is no **click here to view more on microsoft exchange** message. No speed issues - all messages appear in inbox.

`User2` on `Computer2`

- seeing the same issue as first scenario

**what I have tried**

- I compared add-ins - the are all the same for the users and computers
- Tried running in /safe mode - user fails to to login to the domain so can't test
- Tried running with /cleanviews - no difference
- Changing cache exchange mode settings from 12 months to all, and also tried disabling entirely - this appears to load the messages but outlook runs super slowly

**what i noticed**

- The exchange cache settings are identical for all scenarios.
- Under the `Folder` tab, the `View on Server` option is greyed out in cases where Outlook is working well. When seeing the issue, I am able to click this, at which point Outlook runs super slowly

How is this even possible? It appears to not be a computer setting OR a user setting, as the same user is only experiencing it on 1 computer, yet a different user gets the same on a machine where user1 doesn't get the issue.

## Is there a way to get all outlook setting (maybe via a script) and compare with those retrieved from another machine?

If not - how can I possible troubleshoot this issue?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Exchange? Have you tried new Outlook profiles? Does it happen if you disable cached mode for the profile?